# Set a colormap under a graph

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, color-mapping

I know this is well documented, but I'm struggling to implement this in my code.

I would like to shade the area under my graph with a colormap. Is it possible to have a colour, i.e. red from any points over 30, and a gradient up until that point?

I am using the method fill_between, but I'm happy to change this if there is a better way to do it.

```
def plot(sd_values):

    plt.figure()
    sd_values=np.array(sd_values)
    x=np.arange(len(sd_values))
    plt.plot(x,sd_values, linewidth=1)
    plt.fill_between(x,sd_values, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    plt.show()
```

This is the result at the moment. I have tried `axvspan`, but this doesnt have `cmap` as an option.  Why does the below graph not show a colormap?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if the `cmap` argument should be part of the `fill_between` plotting command. In your case probably want to use the `fill()` command btw.

These fill commands create polygons or polygon collections. A polygon collection can take a `cmap` but with `fill` there is no way of providing the data on which it should be colored.

What's (for as far as i know) certainly not possible is to fill a single polygon with a gradient as you wish.

The next best thing is to fake it. You can plot a shaded image and clip it based on the created polygon.

```
# create some sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = np.sin(4 * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x) * 120

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot only the outline of the polygon, and capture the result
poly, = ax.fill(x, y, facecolor='none')

# get the extent of the axes
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()

# create a dummy image
img_data = np.arange(ymin,ymax,(ymax-ymin)/100.)
img_data = img_data.reshape(img_data.size,1)

# plot and clip the image
im = ax.imshow(img_data, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.Reds_r, extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax], vmin=y.min(), vmax=30.)

im.set_clip_path(poly)
```

The image is given an extent which basically stretches it over the entire axes. Then the clip_path makes it only showup where the `fill` polygon is drawn.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, its, not quite what I wanted, as I really need it to be a colour over a certain value, but it will be useful!

Comment: Thats certainly possible with this method. Ive updated my answer a little. Notice how the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments of `imshow` control the shading.

Comment: in my code, what would `img_data` be? `sd_values`? also, strangely when I plot it, the colours are backwards, i.e. white at top, dark red at bottom

Comment: `img_data` is an array with values running between the min and max values of the y-axis. You don't have to do anything with it. You can change the cmap from `Reds` to `Reds_r` to change the colors.

Answer (score 3):

I think all you need is to do the plot of the data one at a time, like:

```
    import numpy
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.cm as cm
    import matplotlib.colors as colors        

    # Create fake data
    x = numpy.linspace(0,4)
    y = numpy.exp(x)

    # Now plot one by one
    bar_width = x[1] - x[0]  # assuming x is linealy spaced
    for pointx, pointy in zip(x,y):
        current_color = cm.jet( min(pointy/30, 30)) # maximum of 30
        plt.bar(pointx, pointy, bar_width, color = current_color)       

    plt.show()
```

Resulting in:
[image]